# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is not working inside a method

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, scriptmanager

I have a method which return type is string.
From the method i want to call a javascript method which is inside .aspx page.But the javascript method is not getting called.
below is my code

```
private string test()
{
   if(somecondition)
   {
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "HideSlider1", "HideSlider();", true);
   }
   return stringvalue;
}
```

Comment: Check `HideSlider();` is outputted or not.

Comment: Try using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`. BTW, is your `test` method in the `aspx` code behind page or in somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ClientScript` class instead of `ScriptManager`

```
private string test()
{
   if(somecondition)
   {
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "HideSlider1", "HideSlider();", true);
   }
   return stringvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private string test()
{
    if(somecondition)
    {
         ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(), "HideSlider1", "<script type='text/javascript'>HideSlider();</script>", true);
    }
    return stringvalue;
}
```